# how to take a written string shown on terminal and saves it in a text file using C lang?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

am trying to take what has shown up to me on the terminal and saves it whatever was a string an int or anything ... how to take this shown string and append it to a text file ?

like this photo i need to write these strings

```
backup   data      obj          results
```

for example , into a text file but all written in C

example of what i want to do:
[image]

Comment: Use `fopen()` to open the file, and then write the output to the file instead of `stdout`.

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: Code in an image is useless here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why, and then come back and [edit] your post to include the relevant code here, in the post itself, as properly formatted text. If you need more information, see [ask].

Answer (score -2):

You can you use the append operator (>>). For example, `echo 'Hello' >> file.txt`, to append Hello to the file.txt.

Comment: How is this *using the C language* (which is what the question asks)?